# CSS - Text and image in link with text vertically aligned middle

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

Please modify [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/sVx5e/) so as to show me how I can have the text beside the image vertivally aligned beside the middle of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/sVx5e/1/

**HTML**:

```
<div onclick="window.location = '#'">
    <img src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_images/jsfiddle-logo-thumb1.png">
    jsFiddle
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div {
  height: 150px;     /* This is the height of the image */
  line-height: 150px;
}

img {
  float: left;
}
```

Use a `<div>`, not a `<a>` element, when wrapping blocks of elements. IE chokes up when you do...

Comment: Excellent Thank you! However I did use an `<a>` element. I just set `display:block;` on it. Thanks for the concept!

Comment: It's working for me in IE8. Could you site a source that supports your statement of: "IE won't work properly with block `<a>` elements."